# Can not install Windows Service from Bash script

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-services

I have created a Windows Service ( `.NET Console App`) and i do not know how to run my `service.exe` from a bash script.The problem lies in executing 
`[servicename].exe install`

I must mention i have been following this [Guide](https://youtu.be/y64L-3HKuP0)

I am first copying my `Debug` contents to a target folder , and then i install the service.

**Shell script**

```
sname="popwinservice.exe"
path="./Experiments/PopWinService/bin/Debug/*"
dest="D:/service"
cp -R $path $dest
cd $dest && (cmd  "$sname" install)
```

**Output**

> $ ./script.sh Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648] (c) 2018
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> D:\service>

The last line does not execute `$sname install`, it just switches to `cmd`.

Comment: Could you confirm wether you are running wsl, git bash for windows or cygwin ?

Comment: Reading from the `cmd /?` documentation, you should probably write `cmd /C "$sname install"`

Comment: I am running git bash for windows.I have also tried using `/C`